# flask admin one to one inline_models

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-admin

i have those 2 models:

```
@derive_schema
class Organization(db.Model):
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), unique=True, primary_key=True, server_default=sqlalchemy.text("uuid_generate_v4()"))
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    code = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    owner_email = Column(String, nullable=False)
    labels = Column(JSONB)
    status = Column(Enum(OrganizationStatus), nullable=False)
    logo_url = Column(String)
    configuration = Column(JSONB, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

@derive_schema
class PortalSettings(db.Model):
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), unique=True, primary_key=True, server_default=sqlalchemy.text("uuid_generate_v4()"))
    organization_id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('organization.id'), nullable=False)
    portal_settings = Column(JSONB)
    organization = relationship(Organization, backref=backref('portal_settings', uselist=False, lazy="joined"))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.portal_settings
```

and this ModelView

```
class OrganizationView(ConfigurationModelView):
    inline_models = (PortalSettings,)
```

the relationship between organization and portal settings should be one to one,
but i dont understand why in flask admin i got this field when i can add as many portal settings as i want instead of just seen a input field with the `portal_settings` JSONB field

[image: sqla]

Answer (score 1):

Based on this gist
https://gist.github.com/DrecDroid/398a05e4945805bc09d1

i've created PR onto Flask-Admin repo and maybe soon it will be merged. Anyway, you may copy-paste code from Gist and use it in your project

https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/pull/2091